# How to correct Python-PDAL "RuntimeError: weakly_canonical.: The device is not ready...."

Tags: python, pdal

I'm failing to get pdal to work in a conda environment. I can install python-pdal from conda forge just fine, but when I try to import the pdal package into python I get the following error:

```
>>> import pdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\wik191\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\pdalenv\Lib\site-packages\pdal\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    inject_pdal_drivers()
  File "C:\Users\wik191\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\pdalenv\Lib\site-packages\pdal\drivers.py", line 66, in inject_pdal_drivers
    drivers = libpdalpython.getDrivers()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: weakly_canonical: The device is not ready.: "D:/bld/pdal_1681477221620/_h_env/Library/bin"
```

I can run pdal from the commandline using pipelines, but the python package is what is failing me. I'm using a new installation of Anaconda python 3.11.3, and am installing python-pdal in a fresh environment. My computer has no D: so I assume it's just looking in the wrong location for the drivers, but I don't know how to correct this.

EDIT: I have additionally tried to install python-pdal directly into my base conda environment, which results in a different, but similar error:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\wik191> python
Python 3.10.8 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Nov 22 2022, 08:16:53) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pdal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\wik191\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdal\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import libpdalpython
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing libpdalpython: The specified module could not be found.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you activated your `pdalenv` conda env?

Comment: @user2856, yes the pdalenv environment is active. Interestingly, I just tried installing python-pdal directly into the base environment and received a slightly different error. I've added the additional information to the question above.

Comment: Don't install stuff into `base`.  Did you install `python-pdal` while creating the env? `conda create -n pdalenv -c conda-forge python-pdal plus any other desired packages`. I just did and works for me.

Comment: @user2856 I know that generally packages shouldn't be installed in `base`. I tried it purely for testing purposes to cover all bases and I can always reinstall. I had tried installing python-pdal at the same time as creating the fresh environment with the same approach you've listed as well as creating the env first, and then installing python-pdal. No luck either way.

Comment: Unofrtunately not an answer or fix, just a comment: I have the same error, but only when trying to run scripts from PyCharm. There is no error with import pdal when starting Python in the command prompt or when executing a Python script using PDAL in the command prompt.. I am using the same Anaconda environment in both cases.

Comment: Getting the same error, I think it was recently broken by some recent change because I was able to get an environment successfully working a few months ago.